# django how to check the type of a file uploaded from mobile

Tags: python, django, file, mobile, upload

I created a django app which lets users upload music and play them online

This is my model

```
from django.db import models

class Song(models.Model):

    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False)
    artist=models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False)
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,null=False,blank=False)
    file = models.FileField(null=False,blank=False)
```

I created a view that adds a new song to the currently logged user, by checking if the file type is audio or not

```
def add(request):

    if 'logged' not in request.session:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    elif request.method=='POST':

        title=request.POST.get('title').strip()
        artist=request.POST.get('artist').strip()
        if title and artist:
            user=request.session['user']
            song=Song(title=title,artist=artist,user=user)
            if len(request.FILES) != 0:
                file = request.FILES['file']
                ext = os.path.splitext(file.name)[1]
                if ext in ['.mp3', '.wav']:
                    song.file=file
                    song.save()

    return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
```

The problem is that it doesn't work for mobile because by default the file system hides the extension so when I submit the file there's no extension and django thinks that the file is not valid when in fact it is

I also updated my code to check for the mime type

```
file = request.FILES['file']
if  file.content_type in ['audio/mpeg','audio/ogg','audio/wav']:
    song.file=file
    song.save()
```

It doesn't work for files without extension because their mime type is application/octet-stream, which can mean any file type.

I guess I should be looking for other alternatives but I don't know how.

Comment: how can a mobile hides extension of file on server side?

Comment: You may try finding a Python library that checks the contents of the file to see if it is an audio file or not. Python's built in `wave` module can do that for `wav` files.